# Docker build removes hyphens from CMD and ENTRYPOINT parameters

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

Docker build removes hyphens from CMD and ENTRYPOINT parameters.

In example C the parameter and attribute is regocgnized by the executable but it doesn't work.

**Example Dockerfile**

*A:*

```
[...]
CMD ["Executable", "--parameter1", "attribute1"]
```

Result:

```
Execuatable: parameter1 not known
```

*B:*

```
[...]
CMD ["Executable", "--parameter1 attribute1"]
```

Result:

```
Execuatable: parameter1 not known
```

*C:*

```
[...]
CMD ["Executable", "----parameter1 attribute1"]
```

Result:

```
Execuatable: --parameter1 attribute1 not known
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Can you provide a more complete [mcve]?  I've never seen `CMD` act this way.

Comment: This is the complete Dockerfile:

`FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk update
RUN apk add gcc g++ make cmake curl curl-dev libcurl libressl-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev git musl-dev

RUN mkdir /tmp/src /tmp/build
RUN git clone https://github.com/taganaka/SpeedTest /tmp/src
RUN cd /tmp/build && cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release /tmp/src
RUN cd /tmp/build && make install

CMD ["SpeedTest", "--test-server", "ookla.myloc.de:8080"]`